# How to use the camera device in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, camera

I am working on an image editing app and therefore googled for it.

I have found some links which says that we can work with camera by ourselves, [like here](http://gigaom.com/apple/seven-apps-to-improve-the-iphones-camera-photos/).

They say we can:

- capture images from within our app (ColorSplash app)
- using accelerometer with camera and some other features

So far my coding doing just opening camera and lets user do the rest.

But I want above listed features... at least the first one.

Can it be done?

Comment: Voting to close because this does not qualify as real question: There's little to no information provided, you do not tell us what you've tried so far, you seem to expect us to find a solution for you for a very complex problem without trying it yourself.

Comment: i have told that i am just opening camera and not doing troubles with it from programming....

Answer (score 1):

i use code from this site to do what your first task do:

http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController

http://trailsinthesand.com/picking-images-with-the-iphone-sdk-uiimagepickercontroller/

these both were links really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@Sawan yes you can do the things u want,capturing of image and its selection please take help from [here](http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/) and also u can use accelerometer in the same way we use in our apps

Comment: No actually that just an example to show you.....that is an imageView which contains the image picked from camera ....at least try that code once by your own and your doubts will be clear